# Can I update order statuses via CSV?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, import, csv, importexport

Is it possible to update order status using CSV? If so, what would be the obligatory data and columns?

Comment: Yes can do this, but you must have to require create custom module where you will define required fields which you want to update i.e status, qty_invoice etc.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Magento doesn’t support this feature. Either you create custom module or use third party module.

https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/order-update-magento-2.html